# The inserted value kept being a 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I don't know what's going on, I selected the price in the table, and when I use it it's fine. In the `<form>` the `$seller` and `$_SESSION['username']` also fine, but in the `buy_item.php` when I try to calculate `$newAmount =  ($row["amount"] - $price);` and tried to see the value it seems like `$price` became `0$`.

**PAGE.PHP**

The sql

```
 $sql = "SELECT seller,price FROM stuff ";
```

in the  table (ALL informations appears fine)

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row["price"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>". $row["seller"] . "</td>";
echo " <td><form action='buy_item.php' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' id='seller' name='seller' value='".$row['seller']."'/>
             <input type='hidden' id='price' name='price' value='".$row['price']."'/>
            <input type='hidden' id='buyer' name='buyer' value='". $_SESSION['username'] ."'/>
             <input type='submit' value='Buy'/>
        </form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

**BUY_ITEM.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("hi", "hi", "hi", "hi");
 if ($conn->connect_error) { 
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
        $seller = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['seller']);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['price']);
   $buyer = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['buyer']);
   $sql = "SELECT username,amount FROM users WHERE username = '" . 
  $_SESSION['username'] . "'";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   if   ($row["amount"] >= $price)  {
      $newAmount =  ($row["amount"] - $price);
        echo ("$newAmount");

        } 
        else
            {
                                echo "Records added successfully.";
      }
      }
      } else { echo "0 results"; }
    $conn->close();
   ?>
```

the `$newAmount` always show up = `$amount` cause `$price` always become = 0

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($_REQUEST['price'], $price);`? Also, I don't see you updating the DB.

Comment: Pleassse use parameterized queries. You are misusing the escaping, `$link` is not defined. You also never escape `$_SESSION['username']`. You probably meant to use `$buyer` in your query, that is less secure though. A user could manipulate the form so the ID is different. This would then allow them to spoof as another user. Validate client data server side.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a punt and say that $price has a hidden character or the like in it.

PHP practices type juggling. Internally PHP is a typed language which casts the real type as required.

$_REQUEST provides the value of $price as a string.

When you use it in a subtraction PHP casts it from a string to an integer. Something goes wrong in the cast, it doesn't look like a number, so PHP makes it zero. Your results then occur.

Printing it out with var_dump() as @mr-glass suggested will make this clear.